# WebApi custom filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a log tha needs save all requests to a db.
i created a custom filter and registered it, but it won't be calling when i request the controller.

here is the LogFilter.cs

```
 public class LogFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterAttribute, IFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            string entity = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                entity = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            logModel.RequestLog rl = new logModel.RequestLog();
            rl.IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
            rl.Type = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToUpper();
            rl.URL = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString;
            rl.Operation = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
            rl.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity))
                rl.Entity = entity;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("reqID", new deviceLog.RequestLog().Add(rl).ID.ToString()));
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);


        WebApiConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: DEFAULT_API_NAME,
            routeTemplate: DEFAULT_API_ROUTE,
            defaults: new
            {
                parameter1st = RouteParameter.Optional,
                parameter2nd = RouteParameter.Optional,
                parameter3rd = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        // remove support for xml
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        // force json indentation
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.Indent = true;
    }
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogFilter());
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `OnActionExecuting` be an `override`?  If it's not overriding a base class method then nothing will ever know to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require `HttpActionContext` for Web Api under `System.Web.Http.Filters` namespace:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Please also note `override` here

Comment: i changed the HttpActionExecutedContext  and override the method, but it throws an error
Device.WebAPI.Classes.Filters.LogFilter.OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: @RobsonGmack: Well the attribute has to override *something* in order for the framework to use it.  Maybe the method is called something else?  Maybe you need to implement a different base class?

Comment: found the problem the overide has the Parameter HttpActionContext not HttpActionExecutedContext , tnx for the help :D